# Mouse moving erractically to the bottom left corner Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mouse, touchpad

I have a mouse issue on Ubuntu 16.04 : it moves erratically to the bottom left corner when I touch the pad and click with another finger on the left click area. It results in launching the bin application.

I can deal with the problem but this is frustrating. Do you know how can I cope with it? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you tried turning the touchpad sensitivity down?

Comment: @KristopherIves Yes, it alters the scpe of the problem without solving it. When I do a left click, I still see my mouse going on the bottom left corner...